# Finding <label> and Updating Based on <Input> tag id

Tags: jsoup

Below is my HTML. My requirement is to find the `input` tag `id` value and place the same id value in the `label` `**for**` attribute. Like 
`<label for="beneficiary.trustName">`

---

```
<div> 
    <div class="lbl">
        <label>
            <span id=Trust Name" class="required">*</span>
            Trust Name
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input">
        <input id="beneficiary.trustName" class="inputlgbeneficiary-name" type="text"
        name="beneficiary.trustName" value="" size="30" maxlength="30" onkeypress="return(event);">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do. Although the error handling is non existent. You can add that part yourself.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);

Elements inputContainers = doc.getElementsByClass("input");
for(Element inpContainer : inputContainers) {
    Element labelContainer = inpContainer.siblingElements().get(0);

    Element label = labelContainer.getElementsByTag("label").get(0);
    Element input = inpContainer.getElementsByTag("input").get(0);

    label.attr("for", input.id());
}

System.out.println(doc);
```

Comment: Thank you Alkis. Solution is working fine. Thanks a lot :-)